# RoR - Get Private address of Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the private address, i.e. The internal IP address of the client who accessing my Rails application. My client is having an organization say with a public IP 61.16.175.141. Internally they are having a number of users each having a private IP address in the range of Class C network ranging from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255. I want to find that private IP address of the user.

I tried most of the answers and nothing matches my result. I tried request.remote_ip, it just renders the public IP address of the organization. Sockets are also working in the same manner. Can any one help me on this please. Hope this clarifies my query. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try `X-Forwarded-For` header. If that doesn't work, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)
What exactly do you mean by "private address"? Please edit your question and clarify so that the community can better help you in answering it.

Answer (score 1):

By private address, I guess you mean the IP address allocated to a machine by its native OS? I'm fairly sure this information is unobtainable from outside a private network, as this is masked to a globally unique public address, allocated by the ISP and mapped somewhere at entry point to the users private network. You would somehow need to access the users routing table which will store a list of private addresses to it's own external entry point.